# Flash CC HTML5 Canvas: Instance names are null. How to work around this?

Tags: flash, createjs, flash-cc

I'm whacking through the weeds for the first time, trying to figure out the correct framework calls in CreateJS and I've run aground pretty hard on the fact that Flash CC doesn't seem to apply the instance names to the name fields when it exports to HTML5 Canvas. Is there an easy way to do this?

What I mean is, for an HTML5 Canvas document

```
console.log( this.myItemInstanceName.name )
```

returns null, whereas similar code in an AS3 document

```
trace( this.myItemInstanceName.name )
```

returns the string "myItemInstanceName".

I do a lot of aircraft panels, which generally consist of a panel with a bunch of controls of type switch, dial or btn. I've got a function library that allows me to do the behavior of each control and then it calls a panelUpdates function with a switch statement based on the control name. This lets me do things like light a lamp on the panel wihen a switch is turned on.

I can easily set up the controls, but I can't see a way to hook up to the panelUpdates function the way I'd like because of this silliness with names. Anyone got a good method for populating the proper instance names in or know when Adobe will add it to a Flash CC update?

Thanks in advance,

Eric.

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
var myPanel = this;

myPanel.mcLightSwitch.btnUp.addEventListener( "click", switchUp.bind( this ) ); // as per code snippets
myPanel.mcLightSwitch.btnDn.addEventListener( "click", switchDn.bind( this ) ); // as per code snippets

function switchUp( e ) {
     thisControl = e.target.parent;
     thisControl.gotoAndStop("btnUp");
     panelUpdates( e );
}

function switchDn( e ) {
     thisControl = e.target.parent;
     thisControl.gotoAndStop("btnDn");
     panelUpdates( e );
}

function panelUpdates( e ) {
     switch( e.target.parent.name ) {
          /* NOT WORKING BECAUSE ALL NAMES ARE NULL BY DEFAULT APPARENTLY */
          case "mcLightSwitch":
               if( e.target.name == "btnUp" ) {
                   myPanel.mcFuelLamp.gotoAndStop( "lit" );
               } else {
                   myPanel.mcFuelLamp.gotoAndStop( "unlit" );
               }
          break;
          default:
          break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These case distinctions through string comparison seem unnecessarily error prone; how about something like this instead:

```js
function panelUpdates(e) {
    if (e.target.parent === myPanel.mcLightSwitch) {
        if (e.target === myPanel.mcLightSwitch.btnUp) {
            myPanel.mcFuelLamp.gotoAndStop("lit");
        }
        else {
            ...
        }
    }
    else if (e.target.parent === ...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Hadn't actually occurred to me to try straight comparison, which actually seems to work in a switch statement too. I am still curious as to why Flash CC isn't assigning the .name field string to each instance (or allowing it to be returned properly, at least).

As for if vs switch, there are usually 5 controls minimum on a panel and sometimes up to 20 or so. So it's definitely easiest for me and easier to read if I keep it as a switch.

Comment: Including the name in the conversion process sounds like a good idea, particularly since the EaselJS `DisplayObject` class has a "name" property anyway. You could suggest that in the [support forum](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs), AFAIK the CreateJS authors are also maintaining the "Toolkit for CreateJS" for Flash.

Comment: And `switch` is fine of course, that was just a misplaced Java-ism on my side.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and it was quite annoying.
But I worked around by manually setting the name and then using it.

Eg :

```
this.myItemInstanceName.name = "myItem";
if (this.myItemInstanceName.name == "myItem")
```

Now I know I can directly compare with the object as mentioned above. :)

Comment: I *may* the name issue eventually, by delaying execution until on tick was called? I know for a fact a lot of other stuff started working once I stopped trying to execute until after the first tick at any rate!

http://hvyboots.tumblr.com/post/86342838307/fla-to-html5-canvas-conversion-of-a-simple